# Overlap of time IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

I have little problem with overlap of time in ProgressBar. I have list card. When click this item show activity with display detail Card show progress bar with counts down the time. When time is over, Counts again. When add next Card and click this card show time previous Card. I don't idea why new Card 
has the same time as old Card.

ProgressBarService.class

```
public class ProgressBarService extends IntentService {

    private int interval;
    public static final String KEY_EXTRA_PROGRESS = "progress";

    public ProgressBarService() {
        super(ProgressBarService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ProgressBarService.KEY_EXTRA_PROGRESS);

        if (intent != null) {
            interval = intent.getIntExtra("interval", 0);
            for (int i = interval; i >= 0; i--) {
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("progress", i);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

CardDeatlisActitvty.class

```
public class CardDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Intent service;
    private ResponseReceiver receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView secondTimeTextView;
    private int interval;

    public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        // on broadcast received
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Check action name.
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ProgressBarService.KEY_EXTRA_PROGRESS)) {
                int value = intent.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                new ShowProgressBarTask().execute(value);
            }
        }
    }

    class ShowProgressBarTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... args) {

            return args[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressBar.setProgress(result);
            secondTimeTextView.setText(" " + result + " ");

            if (result == 0) {
                service = new Intent(CardDetailsActivity.this, ProgressBarService.class);
                service.putExtra("interval", interval);
                startService(service);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_details);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            intervalTotpEncrypt = extras.getString("intervalTotp");
        }

        interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalTotpDecrypt);

        progressBar.setMax(interval);
        progressBar.setProgress(interval);

        service = new Intent(this, ProgressBarService.class);
        service.putExtra("interval", interval);
        startService(service);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                ProgressBarService.KEY_EXTRA_PROGRESS));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProgressBarService` doesn't know that the "Card" `CardDetailsActivity` was changed. If `for (int i = interval; i >= 0; i--) {...}` loop doesn't run out and `if (result == 0) { }` is not true then it will behave as you described becouse `ProgressBarService` counter still counts.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // notify ProgressBarService that the card will be changed (reset the counter)
}
```

Mind that when you call `CardDetailsActivity` for the second time (next card) `onCreate()` could be not called.

Comment: The best solution in this case is to use another solution without using InetntServics?

Comment: @Ewelina Maj If the counter only need to work for a single `Activity` from some value to 0 then I would just put the counter inside a thread in this `Activity`. It would be easier. I can of course use a casual `Service`.